# remove repeat values between two columns

Tags: r

I have two columns (v1 and v2) such as:

```
v1 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1) v2 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
```

I want to create a new column (V3). The new column is exactly the same as v2, except that if there is a 1 in v1 that matches a 1 in v2, then that value changes to zero. Thus the desired solution looks like this:

```
v1 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1) 
v2 <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1) 
v3 <- c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
 df$v3 <- ifelse(df$v1 == 1 & df$v2 == 1, 0, df$v2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, subtraction works: `v3 <- v2 - v1`.

If there is ever a 0 in `v2` and a 1 in `v1`, it won't work, but that doesn't seem to be the case in your sample data. If that's a concern, you can amend to `v3 <- v2 - (v1 & v2)`

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this as

```
(!(v1 == v2)) * v2
#[1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems modulo over `2` like below

```
> (v1 + v2) %% 2
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```